# Is there a way to speed up WiX builds?

Tags: wix

I've built an installer using WiX 3.0. The installer contains additional installers that can be run to add functionality at a later time. The "sub" installers are large-ish (totaling ~200MB). WiX builds were around a minute until I added these "sub" installers and then times increase to about 11 minutes. For reference, I'm building to a single .msi output with the EmbedCab="yes". Any tricks out there to speed this up?

Comment: It sounds like this isn't an option for you, but when I set up build systems I often end up using external source files for intermediate builds to speed up the whole process and eliminate the cab compression completely.

On another note - if you embed all the installers anyway, wouldn't it be better to compile it all into a single MSI and use the feature dialog to control feature addition? After all that's what the feature concept is for?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The cab cache will probably save you a lot of time. See my answer to this question: [Reusing WIX components to speed up candle/light](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207020/reusing-wix-components-to-speed-up-candle-light)

Comment: If I had any bacon I'd send it to you because you just saved it. :) Thanks for answer.