# WiX : How to disable creating RestorePoint during installation at least on testing

Tags: wix

When I run my WiX MSI installer it takes too long to get executed, when I checked the log, I found that the MSI create a Windows RestorePoint,
Question is : how to disable this, at least on testing environment, because it waste much time when testing.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***MSIFASTINSTALL***: You can use the [**`MSIFASTINSTALL property`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/nb-no/windows/win32/msi/msifastinstall). You can set it in the property table or via command line:

```
msiexec.exe /i MySetup.msi MSIFASTINSTALL=1
```

Other values you can try are **`3`** (no restore point and simple costing) and **`7`** (no restore point, simple costing and fewer progress messages).

See this previous answer as well: [How can I speed up MSI package install and uninstall?](https://serverfault.com/questions/594660/how-can-i-speed-up-msi-package-install-and-uninstall)

Comment: That's great. Nothing beats a good test box with NVMe or SSD disks though. I have another answer here on [WiX build speed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30032014/speed-up-build-process-of-wix-installer). And there is [another answer here on speeding up builds](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66723368/129130).